# Subharmonic functions problem

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

The problem says:

> For any $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ open set, there is a subharmonic function
>   $\phi:U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $c\in \mathbb{R}$, the set
>   $\{z\in U: \phi(z)\le c\}$ is compact.

I don't know how to start, I only know some equivalent definitions for subharmonic functions and the problem seems too general because i have to find a $\phi$ for every $U.$

Answer (score 2):

Hints: (i) If $f$ is holomorphic it's easy to show $|f|$ is subharmonic. So for example $|z|$ is subharmonic in the plane, and if $a\in\partial U$ then $\frac1{|z-a|}$ is subharmonic in $U$. (ii) If $u$ is usc and $u$ is the sup of a family of subharmonic functions it's easy to show that $u$ is subharmonic.

Indeed, say $u(z)=\sup_\alpha u_\alpha(z)$, where each $u_\alpha$ is subharmonic. If $z$ and $r$ are such that [...], then 
$$u_\alpha(z)\le\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u_\alpha(z+re^{it})\,dt
\le\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(z+re^{it})\,dt,$$hence $$u(z)
\le\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(z+re^{it})\,dt.$$

Comment: (i) is clear but i don't understand (ii). You said "If $u$ is usc.." what is "usc"?

Comment: And if i have such $u$ how do i show that the set in the statement is bounded in order to show that is compact?

Comment: usc is an abreviation for upper semicontinuous. How you show that set is bounded depends on what $u$ is. (You want to construct a continuous $u$ that tends to $+\infty$ at every boundary point of $U$ and also tends to infinity at infinity...)

Comment: I don't quite get it, can you fill in some more details for (ii)?